# How to get another node's current build's parameters?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson

I am running one job on the Master which includes a groovy postbuild script that needs to collect information about the jobs currently running on the other nodes, specifically their parameters.

I have access to the corresponding node, slave, and computer objects, so I have been trying to obtain the current build object using those objects as a starting point, but I haven't had any success using that approach.

If you know how to get the Build object/variables of another node using my approach or a different one, please do share!

Comment: When asking a question about a problem or issue caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem or understand what you are asking. That code should be [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's not a problem with my code, as I haven't really written any yet. It's a way of going about doing something. I am wondering if there is a path through the Jenkins/Hudson class structure to get to a Build object from a Slave/Node/Computer object. Or if someone has done something effectively equivalent to this, I am interested to hear how they accomplished it.

Comment: (offtopic): jenkins best practice: do not run jobs on master

Comment: Are you using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console?

Comment: I am testing things in the script console, but will be running these items in a groovy postbuild script. And for this particular setup, it makes the most sense to run the job on master. Even if I wasn't running it on master, I would still have this problem anyways.

Comment: I now have this...
    `my_run = slave.toComputer().getBuilds().getLastBuild()`
which strangely enough gives me a Run object instead of a Build object, so I'm still not able to get the build parameters from it as far as I can tell.
Oh well, still working on it!

Comment: what means other node ? if it is slave, you shall be able to get those data directly. And better to share your script out to let people really understand what you want in the question.